# Why do I get a segmentation fault when I am trying to insert into a tree*

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
typedef set<short> pos;
typedef struct tree
{
        pos first;
}tree;
class check
{
public:
        pos last;
        void check_set();
};
void check::check_set()
{
        tree *root,p;
        root=(tree*)malloc(sizeof(tree));
        root->first.insert(2);//SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE WHY???
        p.first.insert(3);//NO SEGMENTATION FAULT
}
int main()
{
check obj;
obj.check_set();
obj.last.insert(1);//NO ERROR HERE
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `new` instead of `malloc`.

`malloc` only allocates memory, it doesn't initialize it in any way and doesn't construct the objects that will be living in that memory. `new` on the other had constructs C++ objects. So to get a valid `tree` object (with a properly initialized `first` member), use this:

```
root = new tree();
```

Later, when you want to release that object, use `delete`:

```
delete root;
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> tree *root,p;
> root=(tree*)malloc(sizeof(tree));
> root->first.insert(2);//SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE WHY???
> p.first.insert(3);//NO SEGMENTATION FAULT
> ```

p is allocated on the stack! So it's constructor is called. root's constructor on the other hand is **never** called! You just allocate a memory of the size a tree would need!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `root` doesn't point to a `tree`, it points to a `tree`-sized chunk of allocated memory. Then you try to execute a `set` operation on an internal member, when the set (with its internal structure and well-groomed pointers) isn't actually in there.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` doesn't call the constructor, so neither `tree`'s constructor nor `std::set`'s constructor ever get called and you're trying to populate the *unconstructed* `std::set`. That is why you get segfault.

Use `new` as:

```
root = new tree(); //this allocates memory, and constructs the object as well.

//deallocation
delete root; //call the destructor, and then deallocate the memory
```

Or use placement-new as:

```
root=(tree*)malloc(sizeof(tree)); //only allocates memory
root = new (root) tree; //constructs the object in the memory pointed to by root.

//deallocation
root->~tree(); //call the destructor
free(root);  //and then deallocate the memory
```