# what should I do in C++ for following code in C?

Tags: c++, c

what should I do in C++ for following code in C?

```
struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Should I use "new"?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want to use `new`:

```
shared_ptr<Node> node(new Node);
```

You can find shared_ptr in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), C++0x and TR1. It will handle deallocation for you, ensuring you don't have a memory leak. If you use boost, you want to include  and use boost::shared_ptr.

Comment: <memory> if you use C++0x (std::shared_ptr<T>), <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> if you use boost (boost::shared_ptr<T>).

Comment: @Don Lun: TR1 also has shared_ptr. `<tr1/memory>` and `::std::tr1::shared_ptr`. And TR1 is actually shipping in many compilers and is fully supported, whereas C++0x is generally considered 'experimental' in most compilers now.

Answer (score 4):

Use new and no cast is needed:

```
Node* node = new Node;
```

When finished, use delete instead of free to deallocate the memory:

```
delete node;
```

However, recommend using shared_ptr:

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<Node> node(new Node);
```

With shared_ptr, no need to explicitly delete the struct instance.  When node goes out of scope, it will be deleted (if it hasn't been shared, otherwise it will be deleted when the last shared_ptr that points to it goes out of scope).

Comment: To add to that: keep in mind that `delete`, not `free`, must be used to release memory allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use `new` because `malloc` doesn't call the constructor, so `Node` will not be "constructed" if you use `malloc`which only allocates the required memory.

On the other hand, `new` first allocates the memory and then calls the constructor which is better.

EDIT:

If you use `malloc`, you might run into such problems: (must see)

[Why do I get a segmentation fault when I am trying to insert into a tree*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841981/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-i-am-trying-to-insert-into-a-tree)

Comment: If the code is coming from C it probably didn't _have_ a constructor.

Comment: @Chris: If its C, then you don't have `new` also.

Comment: The code is _coming from_ C. The OP may not have found a need to have a constructor for `Node` yet. Not all `struct`s in C++ have constructors.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not sure. But to the best of my knowledge, all structs in C++ has constructors, even PODs. PODs don't have *user-defined* constructor.

Answer (score 2):

**You should almost always use `new` instead of `malloc` in C++, especially when you are creating non-POD objects. Because `new` will envoke appropriate constructor of the class while `malloc` won't. If constructor is not called for newly-created object, what you get is a pointer pointing to a piece of junk.**

Consider following example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    vector<int> m_array;
    void insert();
};
void check::insert()
{
    MyClass *root = (MyClass*)malloc(sizeof(MyClass));

                    -- This will crash your program because internal vector object
                  v -- has not been initialized yet
    root->m_array.push_back(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Node *node = new Node;`

That should have the exact same effect here.